# Why is my simple C++ program working with queue and fstream erroring out into invalid pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, queue

Here is a github gist of the code, if preferred I can append the code to this question too.

https://gist.github.com/alevnyaa/e917bc2aa1e72aa210d8cff9fa5e922b

When I compile and run this program with g++ 6.3 with c++11 on linux, after working through the first few lines the program crashes after print_queue is called at line 62. As I am not even manually working with pointers or memory, I have no idea what the problem here is.

```
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000606160 ***
```

I can try any suggestions. I am assuming that I am not noticing a simple problem, but I am blinded after looking at it too many times.

Thank you

Here is the code:

Firstly the file D301.txt

```
D301    Capacity 40

1   1               5
2       2       4   
3           3   4   
4        
5       2           
6        
7   1
```

ifqueue.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

void stoq(std::queue<char>& q, std::string s){
  std::queue<char> empty;
  std::swap(q, empty);
  for(char ch : s){
    if(!isspace(ch)){
      q.push(ch);
    }
  }
}

std::string print_queue(std::queue<char> q){
  std::cout << "Queue: ";
  int i = 0;
  while(!q.empty()){
    std::cout << "i" << i;
    i++;
    std::cout << q.front();
    q.pop();
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(){
  std::fstream infile("D301.txt");
  std::string line;
  std::queue<char> q;
  std::getline(infile, line);
  stoq(q, line);

  print_queue(q);

  std::string classroom_name;
  while(q.front() != 'C'){
    classroom_name += q.front();
    q.pop();
  }

  for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
    q.pop();
  }

  std::string capacity_str;

  while(!q.empty()) {
    capacity_str += q.front();
    q.pop();
  }

  int capacity = stoi(capacity_str);

  std::getline(infile, line);
  while(infile){
    std::getline(infile, line);
    std::cout << "fl" << std::endl;
    stoq(q, line);
    std::cout << "sl" << std::endl;
    print_queue(q);
    std::cout << "tl" << std::endl;
  }

  infile.close();
}
```

Was the -1 really warranted?

Comment: Post the relevant code here directly.

Comment: All questions on stackoverflow.com must include complete information in the question itself, instead of links to some external web site that can stop working at any time, rendering the question meaningless. All question of the form "why isn't my code working", must include a [mcve]. See this help center article for more information, then edit your question and include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

What happens when the queue is empty?

```
 while(q.front() != 'C'){
        classroom_name += q.front();
        q.pop();
     }
```

What happens if the queue has less than 8 elements?

```
for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
    q.pop();
  }
```

Comment: Regarding your second point, the folder structure is set so that is not a problem. Regarding your first, once again the file format is standardized.

Comment: Good! The first line crashes though, I typed it.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure as to why the error was as such. However, the fix seems to be changing the function:

std::string print_queue

into

void print_queue

As it isn't actually returning a string.

If anyone can pitch in why I was getting that kind of error, I'll be happy to find out.

Comment: Not returning a value when the function requires it has undefined behavior